# How to know Who is reconciling the Version to DEFAULT(Parent) in Geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, spatial-database, versioning

We have Public DEFAULT version and working Versions(Child) have been created directly from DEFAULT. We have also provided Reconcile-Post Option to group of Users placed at separate locations. Hence sometimes when I go ahead with reconciling my version It says some one else is reconciling the version, Can I identify which USER is reconciling on Database at that moment.